# Detection of left or right turn of car using sensors(accelerometer or others)

Tags: accelerometer, sensors, android-sensors, gyroscope, magnetometer

Want to detect Is car take left turn or right turn on basis of azimuth,pitch and roll values calculated using sensors
Will i able to calculate using these values or need other parameters too?

Any Help will be appreciated :)

Comment: I think it would be reasonably difficult. First, do you know what position the phone will be sitting in? Will it always be facing the driver?